# Issue while configuring site acess for Multi-Site over same drupal content using domain access module

Tags: database, drupal, drupal-7, drupal-modules, shared-data

I have a drupal site with over 100k nodes. I now need to add 2 more domains and share teh content across these domains. Using `Domain access` module i have created the domains and made content type default to all domains. This works great for new nodes.

However, i cant figure out how to bulk assign existing nodes to all. VBO doesnt seem to have a `domain access` integration. Domain content does allow bulk updation but thats only 50 nodes at a time. Doing 100k will take a massive amount of time.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1):

I think you should use multi site in your case. With shared code and shared database architecture you can easily share your nodes among multiple sites/domains.

In following blog I have discussed different architectures of Multi site in Drupal

[Multi Site Architectures in Drupal](http://tech-arif.blogspot.com/2013/06/multi-site-architecture-and.html)

Following blog will help you to setup multi sites

[Multi-Site Configurations & Setup](http://tech-arif.blogspot.com/2013/06/multi-site-configurations-setup.html)